# Como autenticar múltiplos grupos de usuários no Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando criar um ambiente no laravel 5 onde existe a área de acesso de clientes (Frente da Loja) e a área de administração de páginas, produtos, etc. (CMS), porém o problema é que não estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de dividir as sessões, por exemplo: quando eu autentico uma conta como administrador através da área de login do CMS, essa mesma sessão é válida para todo o site, e portanto o administrador pode acessar as urls que só usuários autenticados poderiam, como o Painel de usuário, por exemplo, e vice versa.

```
// CMS ADMINISTAÇÃO
Route::group(array('prefix' => '/admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'], 'roles' => 'administrator'), function()
{   
    // INDEX
    Route::any('/', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminController@Index'));
});

// PAINEL DO USUÁRIO
Route::group(array('middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'], 'roles' => 'client', 'prefix' => '/panel',), function(){
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'panel', 'uses' => 'PanelController@Index'));
});
```

Para isso eu implementes este sistema de roles, que através dos routes identifica se o usuário possui permissão suficiente para acessar aquela área, o problema é que depois de logado a sessão funcionaria em qualquer lugar, e mesmo que eu utiliza-se algum filtro ainda assim não seria permitido eu ter uma conta de administrador logado no CMS e outra conta de usuário logado no site normal, a não ser que eu dividisse a aplicação em 2, o que eu não gostaria de fazer.

Em resumo, o que eu quero é que ambas as sessões possam existir ao mesmo tempo, sem que uma possa acessar o que é restrito a outra.

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170252/como-posso-diferenciar-autentica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-laravel-exemplo-administrador-e-usu%C3%A1ri[acho que isso resolveria seu problema ][1]

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução que vejo para esta situação seria criar um middleware de autenticação para usuários, e outro para administradores.

Comment: Olá, Leandro! Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Recomendo fazer um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo site para conhecer as melhores formas de resposta. Sendo assim, poderia detalhar melhor sua ideia para ajudar o colega?